# Reading horizontal data then transposing it. Looking for a more elegant solution

Tags: sas

I have this horizontal data:

```
Placebo 0.90 0.37 1.63 0.83 0.95 0.78 0.86 0.61 0.38 1.97
Alcohol 1.46 1.45 1.76 1.44 1.11 3.07 0.98 1.27 2.56 1.32
```

But I want it to be vertical:

```
Placebo  Alcohol
0.90     1.46
0.37     1.45
...      ...
```

I successfully read and transpose the data this way, but I'm searching for a more elegant solution that does the same thing without creating 2 unnecessary datasets:

```
data female;
    input cost_female :comma. @@;
    datalines;
871 684 795 838 1,033 917 1,047 723 1,179 707 817 846 975 868 1,323 791 1,157 932 1,089 770
;

data male;
    input cost_male :comma.  @@;
    datalines;
792 765 511 520 618 447 548 720 899 788 927 657 851 702 918 528 884 702 839 878
;

data repair_costs;
    merge female male;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **proc transpose** to do the same.

```
data have;
    input medicine :$7. a1-a10;
    datalines;
Placebo 0.90 0.37 1.63 0.83 0.95 0.78 0.86 0.61 0.38 1.97
Alcohol 1.46 1.45 1.76 1.44 1.11 3.07 0.98 1.27 2.56 1.32
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_);
id medicine;
var a1-a10;
run;
```

Let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: Add a colon modifier to the in-format associated with medicine :$7.  Without the colon you are using formatted input but you need to be using list input.

Comment: Thank you, I like this answer, it's bringing me closer to the solution, but it's not scalable to larger datasets because it defines each column explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the input "data _null_" and "MrBarryObama" you can see the edited version, now you don't have to define each column explicitly.

Comment: Works great! Thank you G. Arima

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrarily wide input data you will have to use binary mode input, which is specified with RECFM=N.

This sample code creates a wide data file in transposed form.  Thus the data file has one row per final dataset column and one column per final dataset row.

The code presumes CRLF line termination and tests for it explicitly.  The input data set is reshaped using a single Proc TRANSPOSE.

```
filename flipflop 'c:\temp\rowdata-across.txt';

%let NUM_ROWS = 10000;  * thus 10,000 columns of data in flipflop;
%let NUM_COLS = 30;

* simulate input data where row data is across a line of arbitrary length (that means > 32K);
* recfm=n means binary mode output, hence no LRECL limit;

data _null_;
  file flipflop recfm=n;

  do colindex = 1 to &NUM_COLS;
    put 'column' +(-1) colindex @;  * first column of output data is column name;
    do rowindex=1 to &NUM_ROWS;
      value = (rowindex-1) * 10 ** floor(log10(&NUM_COLS)) * 10 + colindex; 
      put value @; * data for rows goes across;
    end;
    put '0d0a'x;
  end;
run;

* recfm=n means binary mode input, hence no LRECL limit;
* as filesize increases, binary mode will become slower than <32K line orientated input;

data flipflop(keep=id rowseq colseq value);
  length id $32 value 8;
  infile flipflop unbuffered recfm=n col=p; 

  colseq+1;
  input id +(-1);

  do rowseq=1 by 1;
    input value;
    output;

    input test $char2.;
    if test = '0d0a'x then leave;
    input @+(-2);
  end;
run;

proc sort data=flipflop;
  by rowseq colseq;
run;

proc transpose data=flipflop out=want(drop=_name_ rowseq);
  by rowseq;
  id id;
  var value;
run;
```

There might be a way to speed up reading larger (say, a file with dataline width > 32k) files in binary mode, but I have not investigated such.

Other variations could utilize a hash object, however, the entire data set would have to fit in memory.